# RaspberryPi Webserver /Cant Access Nginx Server via external public ip. What am i missing? Timeout

Tags: node.js, nginx, raspberry-pi, portforwarding, raspberry-pi4

im trying now for hours and didnt get any further. I just got a simple Express app and an nginx server running on my raspberry pi.

Problem: I cannot access it through the external api. I always got a timeout :/

Steps that i took:
Configured Sites-available.

[image]

Checked for listeners:
[[image: Ports 1]

Tried all port-forwarding stuff i could found  in the router settings:
(its german but i guess u get the point)
[image]

Please help me ! Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

The missing point was my router. Not every Router supports to access the external API while ure connected with the youre local internet.

- I turned of the WI-FI on my phone and were able to access the site via external ip adress and the domain routing to it.
- I hotspoted my PC and were also able to access the website

!! Most modern routers allow accessing while you stayed connect locally to the internet, so in most set up guides they didnt mention.

Hope i could help someone in future trouble.

For me it was a waste of 4-5 h. Happy Coding guys!